# Calling type(1/2) returns integer?

Tags: python, python-2.x

So I noticed that calling :

```
print type(1/2)
```

returns an integer, however shouldn't it be a float?

Comment: Why don't try`print 1/2` and check the output?

Answer (score 9):

Try `type(1/2.0)`, this will return float. One of the numbers has to be a float value to get a return value in float.

Python-2.x division operator follows the *Classic Division*. When presented with integer operands, classic division truncates the decimal place, returning an integer (also known as floor division). When given a pair of floating-point operands, it returns the actual floating-point quotient (aka true division).

Example:

```
>>> 1 / 2          # integer truncation (floor division)
0
>>> 1.0 / 2.0      # returns real quotient (true division)
0.5
```

In Python 3.x, division works differently. `type(1/2)` will return type float. Python-3.x division operator follows the *True Division*.

Comment: In python2, `-1/2==-1`, so "truncating the decimal place" might be a bit misleading. (But then, integer division on negative numbers is a braintwister in and of itself.)

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2x, Division without `remainder/divider` added to the quotient=> floor division
If you want to  force 2x to return `true division`(`remainder/divider` added to the quotient) then try.

```
>>>from __future__ import division
>>>2/3
>>>0.6666666666666666
```

But if you need back the previous behaviuor (i.e. floor division) then try

```
>>>2//3
>>>0
```

In Python 3x True division occurs-